# Magento 2 Custom REST API multipart/form-data

Tags: php, api, rest, magento2, multipartform-data

I'm working with Magento2 Custom REST APIs. I need to upload a `.csv` file vai API. I have been searching for a solution to support `multipart/form-data` in my REST API. But unfortunately haven't found proper solution. Help me sharing any idea on how I can support `multipart/form-data` in **Magento2 REST APIs**?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I will be able to help you.

You can add response types to magento REST API by doing the following:

- Create a webapi response renderer
  `{ROOT}\app\code\{VENDOR_NAME}\Webapi\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer`

```
<?php


namespace {VENDOR_NAME}\Webapi\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\RendererInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Webapi\Exception as WebApiException;

class Multipart implements RendererInterface
{
    /**
     * Renderer mime type.
     */
    const MIME_TYPE = 'multipart/form-data';

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMimeType() {
        return self::MIME_TYPE;
    }

    /**
     * @param object|array|int|string|bool|float|null $data
     * @return string
     * @throws WebApiException
     */
    public function render($data) {
        // return reponse according to your needs
        if (is_string($data)) {
            return $data;
        }
        throw new WebApiException(
            __('Internal Server Error')
        );
    }
}
```

- Add that renderer to supported webapi responses
  `{ROOT}\app\code\{VENDOR_NAME}\Webapi\etc\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\RendererFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="multipart" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">multipart/form-data</item>
                    <item name="model" xsi:type="string">{VENDOR_NAME}\Webapi\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Multipart</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Change {VENDOR_NAME} and {ROOT} according to your project and you are good to go.
If you need any clarification, feel free to ask.
EDIT:
The `webapi.xml` is very basic. To get the response type that we created above in respone, you will have to set the Accept HTML Header (in ajax call f.e.) to `multipart/form-data`. Magento 2 API Responses are always rendered by checking this header.
`{ROOT}/app/code/{VENDOR_NAME}/Webapi/etc/webapi.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../app/code/Magento/Webapi/etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/yourMethod" method="GET">
        <service class="{VENDOR_NAME}\Webapi\Api\{API_CLASS_NAME}Interface" method="yourMethod" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Now you just have to set a prefered model for the interface in `di.xml`.
`{ROOT}/app/code/{VENDOR_NAME}/Webapi/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\RendererFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="multipart" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">multipart/form-data</item>
                    <item name="model" xsi:type="string">{VENDOR_NAME}\Webapi\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Multipart</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <preference for="{VENDOR_NAME}\Webapi\Api\{API_CLASS_NAME}Interface"
                type="{VENDOR_NAME}\Webapi\Model\Api\{API_CLASS_NAME}" />
</config>
```

[See this tutorial](https://magecomp.com/blog/create-custom-rest-api-in-magento-2/#:%7E:text=To%20generate%20access%20token%20inside,extension%20folder%20on%20this%20path.) about creating custom API routes / controllers.

Comment: What should be the webapi.xml file? Thanks.

Comment: I also made some changes to the Renderer and di.xml as I had overseen some naming changes.

Comment: How to fetch multipart/form-data in REST API model file? since the above tutorial link is not working